# How to set a multidimentional array in session with rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, session

I am trying to do something like this :

```
session[:continent][:filter] = params[:filter]
```

but it doesn't work, i got this error :

```
You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.[]=
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You need to initialise session[:continent] to be a Hash first. Try this:

```
session[:continent] ||= {}
session[:continent][:filter] = params[:filter]
```